# kafka-spring boot duplicate consumer group id

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm practicing on kafka in springboot. I have **1 topic and 4 different consumer groups**. It is working normally. I made a copy of the java class in which I defined 4 different consumer groups, pasted it into a new java class and ran the application. In this case, I have 8 consumer groups, but the newly added consumer groups have the **same consumer group id as the previous consumers**. Shouldn't the consumer group id be unique? I expected it not to work but it worked. Output and code can be seen below.

Code:

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

@KafkaListener(
        groupId = "ozgur-group-1",
        topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(
                topic = "ozgur-topic",
                partitionOffsets = { @PartitionOffset(
                        partition = "0",
                        initialOffset = "0") }))
void listen1(
        @Payload String message,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset) {
    LOG.info("Received message by group 1 - Message:{} from partition - {} with offset - {}",
            message,
            partition,
            offset);
}

@KafkaListener(
        groupId = "ozgur-group-2",
        topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(
                topic = "ozgur-topic",
                partitionOffsets = { @PartitionOffset(
                        partition = "0",
                        initialOffset = "0") }))
void listen2(
        @Payload String message,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset) {
    LOG.info("Received message by group 2 - Message:{} from partition - {} with offset - {}",
            message,
            partition,
            offset);
}

@KafkaListener(
        groupId = "ozgur-group-3",
        topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(
                topic = "ozgur-topic",
                partitionOffsets = { @PartitionOffset(
                        partition = "0",
                        initialOffset = "0") }))
void listen3(
        @Payload String message,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset) {
    LOG.info("Received message by group 3 - Message:{} from partition - {} with offset - {}",
            message,
            partition,
            offset);
}

@KafkaListener(
        groupId = "ozgur-group-4",
        topicPartitions = @TopicPartition(
                topic = "ozgur-topic",
                partitionOffsets = { @PartitionOffset(
                        partition = "0",
                        initialOffset = "0") }))
void listen4(
        @Payload String message,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset) {
    LOG.info("Received message by group 4 - Message:{} from partition - {} with offset - {}",
            message,
            partition,
            offset);
}
}
```

Output:

Received message by group 2 - Message:1. Hello World from partition - 0 with offset - 0

Received message by group 2 - Message:1. Hello World from partition - 0 with offset - 0

Received message by group 1 - Message:1. Hello World from partition - 0 with offset - 0

Received message by group 1 - Message:1. Hello World from partition - 0 with offset - 0

Received message by group 3 - Message:1. Hello World from partition - 0 with offset - 0

Received message by group 3 - Message:1. Hello World from partition - 0 with offset - 0

Received message by group 4 - Message:1. Hello World from partition - 0 with offset - 0

Received message by group 4 - Message:1. Hello World from partition - 0 with offset - 0

Comment: You don't have 8 groups here. Use `kafka-consumer-groups` CLI to check. Maybe your logger is misconfigured to duplicate each line

Comment: There are 4 consumer groups in the code here, but there is a copy of this code in my program. I have 8 consumer groups together with the copy class.

Comment: 1) Your logs are duplicated, but they only show 4 groups. 2) What do you mean "copy class"? If you literally copied the source code into a new file, then no, nothing would be unique because your groups are all hard-coded to be the same.

Comment: Yes, I literally copied the source code into a new file. I just changed the class name. What I'm wondering here is could it be a duplicate of the consumer group id? For example, suppose I have two consumer groups. Can both consumer groups be named OneCricketeer-consumer-group-id ? If yes, how could it be? How will it distinguish consumer groups from each other? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Also, I don't think the log is a duplicate because when I delete my duplicate class it only outputs one for each. @OneCricketeer